# Async method's return decorated with "NotNullIfNotNull" still returns variable that may be null

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, nullable-reference-types

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull) I can decorate a method with `NotNullIfNotNull` attribute. However the following code does not work:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

var a = await Test("abc");
Console.WriteLine(a.Length);

[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(input))]
static async Task<string?> Test(string? input)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(input);
}
```

I still receives a warning at `a.Length` (Dereference of a possibly null reference):

[image]

<del>I suspect `Task` is causing this issue.</del> I can confirm the issue only happen to `async` (returning `Task`) methods. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: It's marking `Task<T>`, not `T`.

Comment: @madreflection yes I noticed that. How should I decorate it instead?

Comment: The attribute doesn't provide a way to decorate the type parameters.  Feature request.

Comment: It would need an additional constructor that refers to the type parameters.  [`DynamicAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute) does this, but it only needs `bool`s to indicate "this `object` is actually `dynamic`". `NotNullIfNotNullAttribute` would be more complicated, and it would have to have `AllowMultiple` to be `true` so that you can apply it for multiple cases. For example, if your return type is `(string? a, string? b)` and let's say `a` is not null if parameter `x` is not null, and `b` is not null if parameter `y`...

Comment: ...is not null, it needs to express those separately. It's quite involved. I'm sure the compiler team would like to do it, but they have to examine the use cases and make sure they don't design themselves into a corner. Incremental steps help avoid that.

Comment: @madreflection you are right. I found [the discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2793) about it. Been 4 years and there seem to be no solution anytime soon